# Backup of internal and SD storage via script (USB)

Tags: backup, linux, windows, automation, rsync

**tl;dr**

- I want to backup my internal storage and SD card contents when connected via USB cable
- due to potentially large amounts of data I don't want to use WiFi-based programs
- failed attempt at using `rsync` and `gvfs`

Is there anything I can do?

**Full story**

I would like to backup data from my Android based phone (5.1.1 that is currently). I do not want to use an WiFi-based unstable and insecure hacky solutions with SSH and server here and client there (you name it - actually Samsung's very unreliable `kies` software made me think that way).

By now I used a current Linux Mint (18.2), I tried to read data from the phone using `rsync` and the mapped storage from `gvfs` which failed miserably (permission issues, unstable connection).

I would like to script which directories I backup and automate that process as far as possible. Can I make Android act as some sort of virtual device on `Windows/Linux` that allows some sort of file based access? Or a Web-DAV server connected via USB cable? No free cloud solutions (Google, OneDrive, Dropbox), either, please!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try Grsync? Install that and try. The UI is awful but it does the job. I use it to back up phone as also backup selected partitions of laptop to external hard drive

Comment: [See this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/reasons-grsync-awesome-syncing-tool-crossplatform/). It also has a test button that simulates backup and throws up errors if any before doing the backup

Comment: You can install from [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/grsync) and it works on 18.3 also add I read elsewhere, though the comments here indicate otherwise

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot and see if it solves my issues.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the time: error in layer 8 of OSI model. Here is what I did and what I should have done:

**What I did**

I mounted my target external drive using `sudo` (nothing wrong so far) and thus only `root` has permissions to write, `rsync` failed to do anything (which makes sense after all) - even when running using `sudo`.
Where exactly the error was, I am not absolutely sure, but let's focus on

**What I sould have done**

- Mount the external device using the GUI tools (for I am using an encrypted external drive)
- Create a directory in the root of the external drive and `chown` it to your designated user (or group or both)
- Run `rsync`

I created a small script to automate the finding of the `gvfs` path and rsync to external drive:

```
#!/bin/bash

PHONE_VENDOR=0000 # your phone vendor here!  
USERID=1 # your user ID here - possibly `id -u`

PHONE_BUS=\`echo $(lsusb -d ${PHONE_VENDOR}:) | cut -d' ' -f 2\`  
PHONE_BUS=${PHONE_BUS}%2C
PHONE_BUS=${PHONE_BUS}\`echo $(lsusb -d ${PHONE_VENDOR}:) | cut -d' ' -f 4 | cut -b 1-3` #extract vendor ID from lsusb  

SOURCEBASE=/run/${USERID}/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A${PHONE_BUS}%5D
TARGETBASE= # your target base path here

rsync -a --progress ${SOURCEBASE} ${TARGETBASE}  # your rsync commands here
```

I don't know if anything changes (or this script works) when applying an `fstab` entry and then mounting via shell and not relying on the GUI tools.

This works for me and provides a neat way to backup contents from Android phones without copying whole SD-cards or internal spaces.

**UPDATE - First real attempt**

During execution `rsync` started throwing I/O-errors, probably because the process in general was taking very long (got about 50GB to sync). I am now starting over.
It might be a good idea to start a foundation by manually copying all files initially and all further syncing-processes by using `rsync`.

**UPDATE - Second attempt**

So it happens this amount might be too much for one attempt. Maybe this is my crappy smartphone, too. In general it works and after the first initial load-up it will be fine, I guess.